# What is an AppCompat theme in android?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm just starting with Android development so bear with me. I've downloaded Android Studio, and when i start a new project it a theme called `Theme.AppCompat.Light` (even tough I've selected Holo Light when creating a new project). So my question is, why does android use this and what is it useful for? I've tried changing it to `android:Theme.Holo.Light` but it just gives me an error:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

I'm using this SDK configuration:
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18"

So my question is, why would you use AppCompat, and what do i have to do to enable my app to use the Holo theme.

My activity class is just the default that is generated (it extends ActionBarActivity).

Comment: And for some reason placing four spaces in front of my code here doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holo Themes were introduced in API level 14.

Change your `android:minSdkVersion="7"` to `android:minSdkVersion="14"`

If you want to keep it 7 at least, use this project to get the Holo themes: [HoloEverywhere](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)

Comment: Oh i tried using higher API levels but i stopped at 13 :/ Oh well, thanks, it works now! I assume you made a typo and i should change my minSdkVersion to 14, right?

Comment: Holo Everywhere will require you to use custom classes everywhere, that might not be an option.

Comment: All you have to do is use their activity instead of the android activity and use their widgets in place of the regular android widgets.

Comment: Which will break _any_ other library that is available.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you use SDK 7 (Android 2.1) which knows nothing about Holo.
The Android Team provides a compatibility theme that looks (almost) like Holo.

On a side node you should switch to SKD 10 at least, It will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

See the ActionBar was introduced in API 11 so after that to make backward compatible Google released the support library. You and read about that here [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) here you can also find how to use them in your app.Not only for Action Bar Google has support library for backward compatibility for many new features available on new devices and make them work on older devices.

Answer (score 0):

The Default Activity when creating the project inherits from **ActionBarActivity** on min api level 15 or above, I changed this to Activity and now my activity inherits from **Activity**. Now I can change to Holo or other theme. I guess inheriting from ActionBarActivity requires appcompat theme.